# Help me to solve this trigonometrical equation

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve the equation

> $$\sin(3x+a)+\sin(3x-a)+\sin(a-x)-\sin(a+x)=2\cos a$$

I solved up to this part
$$\begin{align}
2 \sin 3x \cos a - 2 \cos a\sin x &= 2 \cos a \\
2 \cos a  \left(\;\sin 3x -\sin x \;\right) &= 2 \cos a \\
\sin 3x - \sin x &= 1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$\sin3x=4\sin x-4\sin^3x$

---

Alternatively,

using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin3x-\sin x=2\sin x\cos2x=2\sin x(1-2\sin^2x)=2\sin x-4\sin^3x$$

Then you can use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots)